# How to make UIButton always on top, and change able to change the subviews?

Tags: iphone, uiview, locking

I am using two views that are `UIScrollView` and `UITextView`. When program runs, `UIScrollView` displays. User can scroll it horizontally and paging enabled. If he taps on it the `UITextView` (which was at back side) comes forward in flip animation. To go back he needs to press back button (at navigation bar) then `UIscrollView` Comes forward. I am doing this just by detecting the `superview` and put the back view at front. All things are working good. Now, I have been asked to put next previous button at `UIScrollView` by pressing using can move left or right. The buttons will be clear colored background and an image at forground. So that looks like arrow.

I was thinking for it an got the idea to put `UIButton` at always on top and make flip in it.

I dont know that it will work or not.

Please tell me any idea if you think different or any sample/tutorial code to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but you can adjust Z position of views using those functions :

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view belowSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview;
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view aboveSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview;

- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view;
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view;
```

Comment: I tried  [self.scrollview bringSubviewToFront:nextbtn];
        [self.scrollview bringSubviewToFront:prevbtn];. But when user scrolls the buttons also goes with scrolls. I mean not next page the buttons are not visible. They are visible only at first page.

Comment: Remember that if you had your element to (0, 0) position IN the scrollView, it will not be visible in second page as second page coordinates start at 768 (if a cell of your scrollview corresponds to the size of the screen). You need to add your scrollView in a container view and add your button in the same container view if you want the button to be visible in all pages.

Comment: or you can move the button when the offset of the scrollview moves (-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender )